# Determine a RangeValidator max value based on another control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rangevalidator

I have a GridView that contains a TemplateField with a TextBox in it (permanently in edit mode, you might say).  The data from the GridViewRow is updated in the database automatically when the TextBoxChanged event fires.  I am looking for a way to add a RangeValidator to the TextBox so that it will not allow values greater than a BoundField from the same row in the GridView.

I have other validators working on this TextBox, including a manually set RangeValidator.  However, in all my googling, I haven't found any examples of making a RangeValidator dynamically pull from a TextBox, so I'm not sure if this is even possible.  If it can pull from a TextBox, is there a way to get that value from a GridView's BoundField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it within a GridView (still no idea how it might work outside the GridView).  Basically it comes down to adding in a data binding section where the max value would be entered (similar to binding a value to the TextBox itself):

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="ShareTextBoxRangeValidator" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="!" ControlToValidate="ShareTextBox" 
    MaximumValue='<%# Eval("Cost") %>' MinimumValue="0" 
    Display="Dynamic" ClientIDMode="Predictable" Type="Double"/>
```

I found that `Bind` and `Eval` work equally well, but left it at `Eval` since it won't be updating the data.

A further note about Validators and GridViews: If you have set your page's `ClientIDMode` to Static, you must explicitly set it back to Predictable (or AutoID) on both the Validator and the control to be validated.  Otherwise you will get key violation errors.